# UITapGesture do not work on xib file in stack view

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, swift4.2

I have a Controller with these items

[image]

In stack view I add one or many xib file as UiView dynamically, this is my xib file Code:

```
class PassengerInfoItem: UIView {
@IBOutlet weak var View_Content: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var Label_AddPassenger: UILabel!


override init(frame: CGRect)
{
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.commenInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.commenInit()
}

func commenInit()
{
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("PassengerInfoItem", owner: self, options: nil)
    self.View_Content.frame = self.bounds
    self.View_Content.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    addSubview(self.View_Content)
}}
```

and this is my controller code:

```
for i in 1...(UserSearchModel.Passengers.AdultNumber)!
    {
        let passengerInfoItem = PassengerInfoItem()
        passengerInfoItem.tag = i
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTapGesture_PassengerInfo))
        tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
        passengerInfoItem.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        self.StackView_AddPassengerInfo.addArrangedSubview(passengerInfoItem)
    }
```

In stack view all passengerInfoItem added successfully but when touch one of those nothing happen and my problem is UITapGestureRecognizer do not work correctly , I checked all isUserInteractionEnabled = true for back View, Scroll View, Card, Stack View but UITapGesture not work

Answer (score 2):

Because you add another instance here

```
 Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("PassengerInfoItem", owner: self, options: nil)
self.View_Content.frame = self.bounds
self.View_Content.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
addSubview(self.View_Content)
```

so the gesture is applied to the back-most view ,  you may need

```
class func getInstance() ->  PassengerInfoItem {
   let vv =  Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("PassengerInfoItem", owner: self, options: nil)?.first! as!  PassengerInfoItem
   return vv
}
```

Then replace

```
let passengerInfoItem = PassengerInfoItem()
```

with

```
let passengerInfoItem = PassengerInfoItem.getInstance()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I got this error: Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x25a69f158) to 'Flightio.PassengerInfoItem' on this line "let vv =  Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("PassengerInfoItem", owner: self, options: nil)?.first! as!  PassengerInfoItem"

Comment: you need to set class for xib `PassengerInfoItem` in Identity inspector

Comment: ok that error solved but these two value is nil "View_Content" "Label_AddPassenger"

Comment: make sure they are connected to ib

Comment: every thing work fine but nothing show(add) in my stack view do you know why?